# html table row text to be aligned in the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the data that are in the column 'Address' to not have margin. To begin from the left because they overflow.
The html , css, and js code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/htmlcsdep/5n2h03nL/11/)

I don't know why but I also tried the

```
<td align="left">..</td>
```

but it didn't worked. Something in css code is blocking me to make this change.

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6v67a/1482/) I would like the two texts to be in the same line ,down in the page , because the one text is changing, but I can't make it together

Comment: Please update your answer to include your html and css in a working code snippet in your answer.

Comment: add a `class` with`padding-left:0px!important;` to that column

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to set alignment in your HTML, set it in your css. You'll need to set `text-align` to `left` and set the padding to `0` on both `th` and `td` elements.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>first</th>
    <th>second</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>second</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the padding on the address cells.

And for the second point you juste need to add a 
`display:inline-block`
http://jsfiddle.net/6v67a/1484/

Answer (score 0):

I worked on you code. If you want the change to happen only on cells in the address Here is an easy fix.
Add a class to the table cells you want to be changed and add this code to the css . It works

```
.classadded{
padding-left: 9px !important;
white-space: normal;
}
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8v3ndcp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to make all td, th text left align then you can use this:

```
div#users-contain table td,
div#users-contain table th {
  border: 9px solid #eee;
  padding: .6em 220px .6em 20px ;
}
```

or if you want different for TD and TH then use this:

```
div#users-contain table th {
  border: 9px solid #eee;
  padding: .6em 120px;
}

div#users-contain table td {
  border: 9px solid #eee;
  padding: .6em 220px .6em 20px ;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead**
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_tr_align